# Zip files not being bucketed

Tags: media-library, buckets

When uploading a `.zip` file to a bucket in the media library, the `.zip` file does not get put in a bucket. I can't figure out why.

E.g.

[image]

The `zip` item is set to be bucketable:
[image]

And I have created a custom rule for these files. It works with any `File` or `Pdf` items, but with `zip` it's never hitting it. Even if the rule wouldn't work for any reason, it should still add the uploaded item to a "default" bucket structure, which it does for other extensions, but not for `zip`.
[image]

Both the uploaded `zip` file and the Zip template are `unversioned`.
I am NOT using SXA.
Sitecore version: 9.3.0

Any ideas what could be the issue? Or does `zip` just not work with buckets?

Comment: What happens if you sync it ? Does it convert to bucketed item ?

Comment: It worked after syncing it, it even applied the custom rule I have applied